# Не устанавливает программы ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, установка

Только установил ubuntu, и сразу же проблема! Скачал chrome, steam с интернета через firefox, нажимаю установить, прогресс бар очень быстро пробегается, и... ничего! Ничего в поиске не найти! В Ubuntu Software в табе обновления нажал установить справа вверху, вроде у всех прогресс бар пошёл медленно, но у всех остановился в конце, и... стоит.

Comment: А что, разве в официальных репозиториях ни стима, ни хрома нет? `sudo apt-get install имя_пакета` что говорит?

Comment: Вот не задача, в ubuntu software нет chrome, steam...

Comment: Хрома там и не должно быть, потому как в убунте - `chromium-browser`. И вывод `apt-get` так и не привели.

Comment: E: Не удалось получить доступ к файлу блокировки /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Ресурс временно недоступен)
E: Не удалось выполнить блокировку управляющего каталога (/var/lib/dpkg/); он уже используется другим процессом?

Comment: `apt-get` надо запускать через `sudo`.

Answer (score 5):

Вы лезете в убунту с привычками качать софт "по-вендовому", из разного рода помоек.

Все линуксы имеют так называемую систему пакетов - прямой аналог Google Play или Apple Store. Для обращения к системе пакетов существуют пакетные менеджеры.

Менеджером можно управлять из консоли, командой

```
apt-get имя_программы
```

или через графический интерфейс - поищите в меню.

Comment: Вот не задача, в ubuntu software нет chrome, steam...

Comment: @Crome там называется chromium. А Steam качайте через apt-get

Comment: E: Не удалось получить доступ к файлу блокировки /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Ресурс временно недоступен)
E: Не удалось выполнить блокировку управляющего каталога (/var/lib/dpkg/); он уже используется другим процессом?

Comment: @Constantor, пакетный менеджер можно открывать только один раз